# How to pass argument from Gradle Plugin to JUnit4 Test Runner?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have access to some variables across multiple projects via a shared Gradle Plugin, and I would like to pass an argument to my test runner from the plugin.

For example, via `adb shell`, the argument would look like this:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -e myarg MYARG com.example.my.test/.MyTestRunner -w
```

Is there a way I could emulate the `-e myarg MYARG` behaviour from Gradle Plugin code?

(Any equivalent approach would an accepted answer though - I just need a way to pass a variable value accessible in my plugin to my Test Runner)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to set a `defaultConfig.TestInstrumentationRunnerArgument` value, along with your Test Runner and listener. So in our plugin code, we have:

```
defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunner = "com.mypackage.MyTestRunnerClassName"
defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunnerArgument("listener", "com.mypackage.MyTestListenerClassName")
```